# MySQL temporary indexes for user-defined queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I am building an analytics platform where users can create reports and such against a MySQL database. Some of the tables in this database are pretty huge (billions of rows), so for all of the features so far I have indexes built to speed up each query.

However, the next feature is to add the ability for a user to define their own query so that they can analyze data in ways that we haven't pre-defined. They have full read permission to the relevant database, so basically any `SELECT` query is a valid query for them to enter. This creates problems, however, if a query is defined that filters or joins on a column we haven't currently indexed - sometimes to the point of taking over a minute for a simple query to execute - something as basic as:

```
    SELECT tbl1.a, tbl2.b, SUM(tbl3.c)
    FROM
        tbl1
        JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
        JOIN tbl3 ON tbl1.id = tbl3.id
    WHERE
        tbl1.d > 0
    GROUP BY
        tbl1.a, tbl1.b, tbl3.c, tbl1.d
```

Now, assume that we've only created indexes on columns not appearing in this query so far. Also, we don't want too many indexes slowing down inserts, updates, and deletes (otherwise the simple solution would be to build an index on every column accessible by the users).

My question is, what is the best way to handle this? Currently, I'm thinking that we should scan the query, build indexes on anything appearing in a `WHERE` or `JOIN` that isn't already indexed, execute the query, and then drop the indexes that were built afterwards. However, the main things I'm unsure about are a) is there already some best practice for this sort of use case that I don't know about? and b) would the overhead of building these indexes be enough that it would negate any performance gains the indexes provide?

If this strategy doesn't work, the next option I can see working is to collect statistics on what types of queries the users run, and have some regular job periodically check what commonly used columns are missing indexes and create them.

Comment: I suggest making the database design, including the indexes available to the users.  If they choose not to use the existing indexes they can wait for the results.

Comment: could be good to "pre-segment" the types of queries, in order to organize physically the datas based on that (i.e. partitionning). The idea is to propose free range of selects, but within defined resultsets, with lower amount of records.

Answer (score 1):

If using MyISAM, then performing an `ALTER` statement on tables with large (billions of rows) in order to add an index will take a considerable amount of time, probably far longer than the 1 minute you've said for the statement above (and you'll need another `ALTER` to drop the index afterwards). During that time, the table will be locked meaning other users can't execute their own queries.

If your tables use the `InnoDB` engine and you're running MySQL 5.1+, then `CREATE / DROP` index statements shouldn't lock the table, but it still may take some time to execute.

There's a good rundown of the history of `ALTER TABLE` [here][1].

I'd also suggest that automated query analysis to identify and build indeces would quite difficult to get right. For example, what about cases such as selecting by `foo.a` but ordering by `foo.b`? This kind of query often needs a covering index over multiple columns, otherwise you may find your server tries a filesort on a huge resultset which can cause big problems.

Giving your users an "explain query" option would be a good first step. If they know enough SQL to perform custom queries then they should be able to analyse `EXPLAIN` in order to best execute their query (or at least realise that a given query will take ages).

Comment: Your link is broken (or seems to be on my phone)

Answer (score 1):

So, going further with my idea, I propose you segment your datas into well identified views. You used abstract names so I can't reuse your business model, but I'll take a virtual example.

Say you have 3 tables:

- customer (gender, social category, date of birth, ...)
- invoice (date, amount, ...)
- product (price, date of creation, ...)

you would create some sorts of materialized views for specific segments. It's like adding a business layer on top of the very bottom data representation layer.

For example, we could identify the following segments:

- seniors having at least 2 invoices
- invoices of 2013 with more than 1 product

How to do that? And how to do that *efficiently*? Regular views won't help your problem because they will have poor explain plans on random queries. What we need is a real physical representation of these segments. We could do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MV_SENIORS_WITH_2_INVOICES AS 
SELECT ... /* select from the existing tables */
;

/* add indexes: */
ALTER TABLE MV_SENIORS_WITH_2_INVOICES ADD CONSTRAINT...
... etc.
```

So now, your guys just have to query `MV_SENIORS_WITH_2_INVOICES` instead of the original tables. Since there are less records, and probably more indexes, the performances will be better.

We're done! Oh wait, no :-)
We need to refresh these datas, a bit like a FAST REFRESH in Oracle. MySql does not have (not that I know... someone corrects me?) a similar system, so we have to create some triggers for that.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ... AFTER INSERT ON `seniors`
... /* insert the datas in MV_SENIORS_WITH_2_INVOICES if it matches the segment */
END;
```

Now we're done!